# How is the Williams test in R related to glht with mcp set to Williams?

Tags: r, dose-response

My objective is simple: to find the minimum effective dose. I want to use the Williams procedure, to say from which it starts. It seems there are different approaches, 1) contrasts method via glht, from which I have to pick the smallest p-value to check whether the trend exists (I guess so!), 2) Williams test, which gives me p-value per each dose. Both methods totally differ in t, p-values, yet both refer to "Williams".

Does it mean, that "Williams" itself refers to a contrasts for trend (monotonous), and the min(p-value) is for the trend, while the "Williams test" also adjusts the p-values according to his algorithm? I'm totally lost.

The data:

```
structure(list(BUN = c(15, 15.2, 14.9, 15.4, 16.8, 14.1, 14.9, 
14.5, 13.7, 12.9, 15.8, 16.6, 12.7, 15.4, 14, 20.8, 19.1, 18.7, 
18.8, 17.5, 21.9, 17.5, 21.3, 20.4, 18.2, 15.4, 15.2, 13, 14.7, 
15.7, 15.7, 13.4, 15.1, 14.2, 15.2, 17.9, 18.2, 21.8, 18.2, 15.6, 
22.3, 18.6, 22, 19.9, 19.6, 21, 21.7, 19.7, 18.8, 18.6, 14.9, 
15.2, 15.2, 12.4, 13.7, 14.2, 15, 14.5, 16.3, 17.1), Dose = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("0", 
"62.5", "125", "250", "500", "1000"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("BUN", 
"Dose"), row.names = c(NA, -60L), class = "data.frame")
```

[image]

The model:

```
m<-lm(BUN~Dose, data=data);
```

First: Williams test

```
> williamsTest(data$BUN, data$Dose, alternative = "greater")

    Many-to-one comparisons using Williams trend test

data: data$BUN and data$Dose
alternative hypothesis: greater
degree of freedom: 54
alpha: 0.05

H0
               t' value t' crit decision
mu1 - ctr == 0    2.328   1.674   reject
mu2 - ctr == 0    2.328   1.750   reject
mu3 - ctr == 0    2.328   1.774   reject
mu4 - ctr == 0    2.967   1.786   reject
mu5 - ctr == 0    2.967   1.793   reject
```

OK, Now the Shirley-Williams nonparametric model to verify

```
> shirleyWilliamsTest(data$BUN, data$Dose, alternative = "greater")

    Many-to-one comparisons using Shirley-Williams test

data: data$BUN and data$Dose
alternative hypothesis: greater
degree of freedom: Inf
alpha: 0.05

H0
               t' value t' crit decision
mu1 - ctr == 0    2.156   1.645   reject
mu2 - ctr == 0    2.275   1.716   reject
mu3 - ctr == 0    2.169   1.739   reject
mu4 - ctr == 0    4.489   1.750   reject
mu5 - ctr == 0    2.303   1.756   reject
```

OK, somewhat similar. So the MED is the 1st one. OK.
Now switch to glht

```
> summary(glht(m, linfct=mcp(Dose="Williams"),alternative="greater"))

     Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses

Multiple Comparisons of Means: Williams Contrasts


Fit: lm(formula = BUN ~ Dose, data = data)

Linear Hypotheses:
         Estimate Std. Error t value  Pr(>t)   
C 1 <= 0   0.1100     0.9422   0.117 0.60256   
C 2 <= 0   2.7950     0.8159   3.426 0.00147 **
C 3 <= 0   2.4600     0.7693   3.198 0.00266 **
C 4 <= 0   2.4925     0.7448   3.346 0.00146 **
C 5 <= 0   2.4340     0.7298   3.335 0.00234 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
(Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)
```

Completely different t-values. Don't know how to interpret the output. The smallest p-value is 0.00146 so I assume there is a trend (lowering?). The first dose doesn't seem the MED.

This topic tells me to make use a different method:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23760401/sequential-use-of-the-williams-test-to-determine-the-minimum-effective-dose-afte

OK, let's check:

```
    > n <- tapply(data$Dose, data$Dose, length)
    > k <- length(n)
    > CM <- c()
    > for (i in 1:(k - 1)) {
    +     help <- c(-1, n[2:(i + 1)] / sum(n[2:(i + 1)]), rep(0 , k - i - 1))
    +     CM <- rbind(CM, help)
    + }
    > rownames(CM) <- paste("C", 1:nrow(CM))
    > CM
                62.5                             
    C 1 -1 1.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00 0.0
    C 2 -1 0.5000000 0.5000000 0.0000000 0.00 0.0
    C 3 -1 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.00 0.0
    C 4 -1 0.2500000 0.2500000 0.2500000 0.25 0.0
    C 5 -1 0.2000000 0.2000000 0.2000000 0.20 0.2

> summary(glht(m, linfct = mcp(Dose = CM), alternative = "greater"))

     Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses

Multiple Comparisons of Means: User-defined Contrasts


Fit: lm(formula = BUN ~ Dose, data = data)

Linear Hypotheses:
         Estimate Std. Error t value  Pr(>t)    
C 1 <= 0   2.2000     0.9422   2.335 0.02449 *  
C 2 <= 0   2.3950     0.8159   2.935 0.00569 ** 
C 3 <= 0   2.1933     0.7693   2.851 0.00691 ** 
C 4 <= 0   3.0150     0.7448   4.048 < 0.001 ***
C 5 <= 0   2.4340     0.7298   3.335 0.00221 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
(Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)
```

Now it resembles a bit the shirleyWilliamsTest in terms of the t statistics. The first dose appears to be the MED. But is this algorithm correct?

OK, the last check - two.sided test between the shirleyWilliamsTest and the glht:

```
 > shirleyWilliamsTest(data$BUN, data$Dose, alternative = "two.sided")

    Pairwise comparisons using Shirley-Williams test

data: data$BUN and data$Dose

    ctr                
mu1 0.031              
mu2 0.015              
mu3 0.019              
mu4 <0.0000000000000002
mu5 0.013              

P value adjustment method: boot
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
Warning message:
In shirleyWilliamsTest.default(data$BUN, data$Dose, alternative = "two.sided") :
  As alternative is 'two.sided', method was set to 'boot'.

> summary(glht(m, linfct = mcp(Dose = CM), alternative = "two.sided"))

     Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses

Multiple Comparisons of Means: User-defined Contrasts


Fit: lm(formula = BUN ~ Dose, data = data)

Linear Hypotheses:
         Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
C 1 == 0   2.2000     0.9422   2.335  0.04860 *  
C 2 == 0   2.3950     0.8159   2.935  0.01125 *  
C 3 == 0   2.1933     0.7693   2.851  0.01427 *  
C 4 == 0   3.0150     0.7448   4.048  < 0.001 ***
C 5 == 0   2.4340     0.7298   3.335  0.00401 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
(Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)
```

OK, both agree to the magnitude of order, but values are different. When I set the Dose to "Williams", it returns completely something different.

Does anyone know how to get the MED in R RELIABLY?

Do I need to additionally adjust the p-values? I understand the contrast is only a way of comparison, but there are, actually, multiple ones. Which one should I use? How does it correspond on the p-values from the original Williams procedure?

EDIT: Found the answer in this book - what glht does has a little common with the original Williams procedure, which is the industry standard in toxicology. What glht offers is of little important to the industry, sadly: https://books.google.pl/books?id=dT1jDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PT144&ots=yIX6dITHO_&dq=%22williamsTest%22%20glht%20R&hl=pl&pg=PT144#v=onepage&q=%22williamsTest%22%20glht%20R&f=false

Comment: In order to understand the output of `glht` with Williams contrasts, you have to understand what each contrast is that is being tested in the output.  You can see from the contrast matrix, that these contrasts make sense as a series only when there is monotonicity across dose levels.  Assuming your data frame is called `Data`, the contrast matrix can be obtained with `n=table(Data$Dose); contrMat(n, type="Williams")`

Comment: Thank you very much. Well, you're right, my data are not suitable for the Williams test, just wanted to get consistent results. The original Williams test gives me p-values per each Dose using step-up analysis with quite complicated method of calculating the p-values. This Williams uses completely reversed approach and results something far from the Williams test. Only Dunnett gives something comparable, but is less sensitive than the Williams test (well, true, it assumes trend). Just wanted to find a way to reproduce the williamsTest with glht. I'm unable, so far.

Comment: OK, found answer here - briefly: what glht calculates is NOT the result from the Williams test williamsTest() (williamsTest agrees with SAS, which is the most important thing to me): https://books.google.pl/books?id=dT1jDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PT144&ots=yIX6dITHO_&dq=%22williamsTest%22%20glht%20R&hl=pl&pg=PT144#v=onepage&q=%22williamsTest%22%20glht%20R&f=false

Comment: It may be helpful to readers to summarize what you found.  Are you using the PMCMRplus package in R to calculate Williams test?  And those results are consistent with the ones SAS gives?

Comment: I summarized my findings in a separate answer. I hope it will help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, got it.
TL;DR:

1. **it is not possible to do this via the Williams contrast in glht solely**. This is **not** the contrast we want here.
2. For ideally monotonous trend, the Dunnett approach is valid (means,
   SE, t statistics) - it uses the same contrast as the Williams test.
   The difference is in critical values used in testing. The critical
   values of the Williams' t statistics have to be provided externally.
   If provided, the results agree ideally with the results of two
   functions doing the Williams Test I evaluated.
3. Dunnett contrast should be used along with the "free" adjustment for
   better sensitivity.
4. for non-monotonous trend, Dunnett contrast is too simplistic and we
   don't get valid results. It can be handled externally, but it
   requires extra programming and does not give any advantage over
   using dedicated function.
5. "Williams contrast" verifies the trend in responses vs. doses.
6. "Williams test" indicates the MED.

Now, let me tell the story, step by step
Step 1)
I used two functions:
PMCMRplus::williamsTest - more accurate regarding the calculation of degrees of freedom, based on the isotonic regression. Uses tabulated critical values provided by Williams (only for a=0.05)
The source code can be found here: https://rdrr.io/cran/PMCMRplus/src/R/williamsTest.R

StatCharrms::williamsTest - this is a little bit simpler function, but unfortunately, the package is removed from CRAN. It's due to dependency on another package, which does not pass some CRAN quality checks. Luckily, the Williams test does not depend on it, so I could safely use the code, available in the [CRAN archive](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/StatCharrms/). Now, I could compare both functions to validate the outcomes.

2. As the StatCharrms::williamsTest function is simpler and easier to understand, I went through its code step by step, to understand what is going on, namely, how the test statistics, DF, SE and p-value is calculated.
3. To make it simpler and focus on the major idea, I created another data set, with perfectly monotonous response. It allowed me to bypass a lot of code, which handles the non-monotonous cases.

The data:

```
structure(list(Dose = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("0", 
"10", "20", "50", "100"), class = "factor"), Response = c(2.08715025123701, 
1.13932702656069, 0.613727902326215, 2.12358542318002, 0.240154342642407, 
2.14895910322903, 0.15752374106325, 1.39141334039277, 1.89137724231864, 
-0.335258712554325, 1.49812347783493, 0.988413197051174, 1.77574391664229, 
0.311402064620783, 1.01301366594251, 2.48228400775579, 1.26849016380803, 
1.92319094827512, 0.879105402383558, 0.0706083452852893, 2.68907430915287, 
1.47500884455923, 0.103888611550029, 3.86912259199149, 1.61309118302257, 
0.873916987353586, 3.69528180729257, 2.68813821856926, 2.10037160524839, 
2.5220520133979, 3.3740186581977, 4.79665877645507, 4.52766070850153, 
2.07336940413649, 4.15339849564175, 4.52681366589956, 4.4682609759767, 
1.37568269071579, 3.56464257498472, 5.77963332091796, 4.99679453863953, 
2.49072381935414, 2.53633128811656, 4.69110955231555, 4.02594451442771, 
5.16129056387748, 4.49382666167731, 4.28099936350917, 4.38366184279928, 
4.36625503539133)), .Names = c("Dose", "Response"), row.names = c(NA, 
-50L), class = "data.frame")
```

[image]

4. I calculated all necessary parts, based on the code available in the (removed) CharmStats package:

(Sorry, I know this code is **ugly** - I copy/pasted it from the sources and simplified here and there just to experiment)

```
Vars <- by(df[["Response"]],as.factor(df[["Dose"]]),var,na.rm=TRUE)
S <- sqrt(sum(Vars*(N-1))/(sum(N)-length(N)))
Se <- (S*sqrt(1/N+1/N[1]))[1:{length(N)-1}]
DF=sum(N)-length(N)

Y.tilde <- as.vector(by(df[["Response"]],df[["Dose"]],mean,na.rm=TRUE))
T <- (Y.tilde[1]-Y.tilde)/Se
if (direction=='INCREASING'){
  T<-T*-1
}
#Table look up
K=length(N)-1   
Row=which(DTtable$df==DF)
if (length(Row)==0){  #sets the df to 10000 if the df >= 121
  Row<-119
}
Cols<-1+1:{2*(K-1)}
B<-DTtable[Row,Cols[which(Cols %% 2 == 1)]]
Q<-DTtable[Row,Cols[which(Cols %% 2 == 0)]]

#Calculate t crit   
W=N[1]/N[-c(1,2)]
Tcrit<-unlist(Q-10^(-2)*B*(1-1/W))
QT1<-qt(0.95,DF)    
Tcrit<-c(QT1,Tcrit)
Diff <- Y.tilde[-1] - Y.tilde[1]
T <- Diff/Se
```

Let's compare the results with the another Williams test:

```
> data.frame(mean=Y.tilde[-1], baseline=Y.tilde[1], Diff, Se, T, Tcrit, MED=T>Tcrit)
       mean baseline       Diff        Se         T    Tcrit   MED
   1.221038 1.145796 0.07524155 0.4639577 0.1621733 1.679427 FALSE
Q2 2.162995 1.145796 1.01719865 0.4639577 2.1924385 1.755000  TRUE
Q3 3.864014 1.145796 2.71821796 0.4639577 5.8587630 1.780000  TRUE
Q4 4.142694 1.145796 2.99689775 0.4639577 6.4594208 1.792000  TRUE
> williamsTest(Response~Dose, data)

    Many-to-one comparisons using Williams trend test

data: Response by Dose
alternative hypothesis: greater
degree of freedom: 45
alpha: 0.05

H0
               t' value t' crit decision
mu1 - ctr == 0    0.162   1.679   accept
mu2 - ctr == 0    2.192   1.757   reject
mu3 - ctr == 0    5.859   1.781   reject
mu4 - ctr == 0    6.459   1.793   reject
```

OK, almost perfect agreement. Differences come from different methods of calculations in both packages. The second one is much more advanced. Note: the labels are opposite but consistent - I used MED, which is mirrored "accept/reject" (BTW, it should be "don't reject" rather than "accept").

5. Let's use glht with Dunnett contrast (all vs. baseline) and check, if the SEs and t are the same:

   (dun <- summary(glht(aov(Response~Dose, data=data), linfct=mcp(Dose="Dunnett"),alternative="greater")))

   Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses

   Multiple Comparisons of Means: Dunnett Contrasts

   Fit: aov(formula = Response ~ Dose, data = data)

   Linear Hypotheses:
                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>t)
   10 - 0 <= 0   0.07524    0.46396   0.162 0.7429
   20 - 0 <= 0   1.01720    0.46396   2.192 0.0533 .
   50 - 0 <= 0   2.71822    0.46396   5.859 <0.001 ***

   ### 100 - 0 <= 0  2.99690    0.46396   6.459 <0.001 ***

   Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘***’ 0.01 ‘’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
   (Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)

Perfect agreement. So, instead of calculating everything manually, we could use the results from glht together with the critical values calculated before and the get correct values.

But - it doesn't make much sense, since we have the williamsTest() function ready to go. There is also its non-parametric counterpart, shirleyWilliamsTest().

When it comes the the original data I posted previously (taken from some book), it gets complicated. It seems that the test searches for a "changing point" and divides it into ranges with consistent trend (look at the t values and relate it to the dose and the plot in my first post). I have to investigate it closer, when find some time.

```
> williamsTest(BUN~Dose, data2)

    Many-to-one comparisons using Williams trend test

data: BUN by Dose
alternative hypothesis: greater
degree of freedom: 54
alpha: 0.05

H0
               t' value t' crit decision
mu1 - ctr == 0    2.328   1.674   reject
mu2 - ctr == 0    2.328   1.750   reject
mu3 - ctr == 0    2.328   1.774   reject
mu4 - ctr == 0    2.967   1.786   reject
mu5 - ctr == 0    2.967   1.793   reject
---
> NewwilliamsTest(data2, resp = "BUN", trt = "Dose",direction = "increasing")
   Dose Y.Tilde    Y0 Se.Diff DF  Will TCrit Signif
Q5 1000   17.54 14.74  0.9422 54 2.967 1.792      *
Q4  500   17.54 14.74  0.9422 54 2.967 1.785      *
Q3  250   16.93 14.74  0.9422 54 2.328 1.773      *
Q2  125   16.93 14.74  0.9422 54 2.328 1.749      *
   62.5   16.93 14.74  0.9422 54 2.328 1.674      *
```

So, finally, what does the Williams contrast do in the ghlt? It evaluates the trend in responses. It won't tell you the minimum effective doses. It's worth noting there are advanced, model-based tools available in R, stored in the DoseFinding package.

So, if your objective is to find the MED in the monotonous, use the Williams test, otherwise - Dunnett. If you want to confirm the trend in dose-response, the Williams (and Marcus) contrast is the way to go.

What's the advantage of Williams over Dunnett? In the default setting (for Dunnett), Williams is more effective in case of monotonous trend than Dunnett. That's because the Dunnett procedure uses a single-step adjustment (the same critical value for all tests based on joint normal/t distribution). If we specify "free", it employs a stepwise method, using different critical values for each dose, which is more sensitive and gives results similar to the Williams test.

```
> williamsTest(Response~Dose, data)

    Many-to-one comparisons using Williams trend test

data: Response by Dose
alternative hypothesis: greater
degree of freedom: 45
alpha: 0.05

H0
               t' value t' crit decision
mu1 - ctr == 0    0.162   1.679   accept
mu2 - ctr == 0    2.192   1.757   reject
mu3 - ctr == 0    5.859   1.781   reject
mu4 - ctr == 0    6.459   1.793   reject
---
> (dun <- summary(glht(aov(Response~Dose, data=data), linfct=mcp(Dose="Dunnett"),alternative="greater"), test=adjusted("free")))

     Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses

Multiple Comparisons of Means: Dunnett Contrasts


Fit: aov(formula = Response ~ Dose, data = data)

Linear Hypotheses:
             Estimate Std. Error t value   Pr(>t)    
10 - 0 <= 0   0.07524    0.46396   0.162   0.4359    
20 - 0 <= 0   1.01720    0.46396   2.192   0.0307 *  
50 - 0 <= 0   2.71822    0.46396   5.859 5.92e-07 ***
100 - 0 <= 0  2.99690    0.46396   6.459 6.96e-08 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
(Adjusted p values reported -- free method)

> (dun <- summary(glht(aov(Response~Dose, data=data), linfct=mcp(Dose="Dunnett"),alternative="greater"), test=adjusted("single-step")))

     Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses

Multiple Comparisons of Means: Dunnett Contrasts


Fit: aov(formula = Response ~ Dose, data = data)

Linear Hypotheses:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>t)    
10 - 0 <= 0   0.07524    0.46396   0.162 0.7429    
20 - 0 <= 0   1.01720    0.46396   2.192 0.0533 .  
50 - 0 <= 0   2.71822    0.46396   5.859 <0.001 ***
100 - 0 <= 0  2.99690    0.46396   6.459 <0.001 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
(Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)
```

Last, but not least, the simplest, liner model based approach reports consistent result for delta=1:

```
> MCPMod(data, list(linear = NULL), alpha = 0.05, pVal = TRUE, clinRel =1)
MCPMod
PoC (alpha = 0.05, one-sided): yes 
Model with highest t-statistic: linear 
Model used for dose estimation: linear 
Dose estimate: 
MED2,80% 
      31
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not my field, so take any advice I give with a grain of salt.

[This article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/236653799_Statistical_evaluation_of_toxicological_assays_Dunnett_or_Williams_test_-_Take_both) suggests that Williams test assumes monotonicity of the increasing doses.  That is, that each dose has a result at least as high as the previous dose.  If this is in fact an assumption of the test, your data do not meet this assumption.

[Another approach](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/fc7e/0df8eca3642fd215561ebd7e09f7135f91d9.pdf) is simply to define MED as the minimum dose where the mean of the response is significantly greater than the control.  In this case, Dunnett contrasts can be used, and the MED identified by inspection.

```
summary(glht(m, linfct=mcp(Dose="Dunnett"), alternative="greater"))

   ### Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses
   ###     
   ###     Multiple Comparisons of Means: Dunnett Contrasts
   ###     
   ###     Linear Hypotheses:
   ###                   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>t)    
   ###     62.5 - 0 <= 0   2.2000     0.9422   2.335 0.0453 *  
   ###     125 - 0 <= 0    2.5900     0.9422   2.749 0.0168 *  
   ###     250 - 0 <= 0    1.7900     0.9422   1.900 0.1103    
   ###     500 - 0 <= 0    5.4800     0.9422   5.816 <0.001 ***
   ###     1000 - 0 <= 0   0.1100     0.9422   0.117 0.7964
   ###
   ### (Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)
```

Note also that this approach makes it easy to identify a treatment with a minimum difference in response.  For example, if we wanted a significant increase in response with a mean difference of at least 3, only the 500 treatment would meet this requirement.

Note that the *p* value adjustment method may make a difference.  Using the *emmeans* package, with it's dunnettx adjustment, the *t* values are similar, but the adjusted *p* values differ.

```
library(emmeans)

emmeans(m, specs = trt.vs.ctrl ~ Dose)

   ###     $contrasts
   ###      contrast estimate    SE df t.ratio p.value
   ###      62.5 - 0     2.20 0.942 54 2.335   0.0937 
   ###      125 - 0      2.59 0.942 54 2.749   0.0350 
   ###      250 - 0      1.79 0.942 54 1.900   0.2256 
   ###      500 - 0      5.48 0.942 54 5.816   <.0001 
   ###     1000 - 0      0.11 0.942 54 0.117   0.9990 
   ###    
   ###     P value adjustment: dunnettx method for 5 tests
```

That being said, if the goal is only to find the MED, fewer hypotheses are actually tested, and a less severe *p* value adjustment can be made.  That is, if *Treatment 1* is compared to *Control* and is not different, and then *Treatment 2* is compared to *Control* and is different, then only two hypotheses were tested and the rest can be ignored.  However, one may still want to make all tests in the Dunnett comparisons, since the results are likely to be of interest.

Comment: Found the answer in this book - what glht does has a little common with the original Williams procedure, which is the industry standard in toxicology. What glht offers is of little important to the industry, sadly: https://books.google.pl/books?id=dT1jDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PT144&ots=yIX6dITHO_&dq=%22williamsTest%22%20glht%20R&hl=pl&pg=PT144#v=onepage&q=%22williamsTest%22%20glht%20R&f=false

But thank you for your effort.

Comment: Yeah, when *glht* uses terms like "tukey" and "williams" they are just names it gives to how contrasts are defined.  This causes confusion because it doesn't mean "Tukey test" or "Williams test".

Comment: Well, at least for Tukey it works perfectly: both contrasts and the p-value (if only the single-step option is used). If you compare the emmeans, TukeyHSD and glht, it all agrees. The only difference is that TukeyHSD and emmeans use the Tukey distribution (approximated with precision to the 4th decimal digit), while glht uses multidimensional t distribution via Monte Carlo (mvtnorm), so the results vary a little (unless the seed is set), but agree to 3 decimal points with the formers. Regarding Williams - glht does what's expected: tests contrasts. Not the levels of doses itself, as expected.

Comment: Actually, even the TukeyHSD is not the original Tukey test. Instead, it's the Tukey-Crammer test, allowing for unbalanced groups. Which is good for us all, saving us from headache when analyse the real data sets.